# SubView not adjusting on device rotation

Tags: ios

I am adding a subview to my view. Everything works fine. My app supports autorotation.
When i rotate my device, my parent views shouldautorotate/willanimate gets called but subviews shouldautorotate/willanimate is not getting called. Because of this i am not able to set the position of UI components of subview.

```
viewController = [[abcController alloc] initWithNibName:@"abcController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
```

Any pointer will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you cannot functionally add views from one view controller into the view tree of another view controller and expect the second view controller to get messages.

You need to either

1. Have the view your adding be part of your first `UIViewController` (not a second `UIViewController`)
2. Use the `addChildViewController` methods to add the second view controller as a child of the first view controller (which will allow these messages to get forwarded).

Comment: Thanks for this!  I spent a day trying to figure out why my subview wouldn't rotate.  You must call addChildViewController!

Answer (score 1):

Your view is lacking the proper autoresize setting:

```
viewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Apart from this, if you mean that your `abcController`'s `shouldautorotate/willanimate` are not getting called, well, that is normal behavior.

Your main controller should implement some sort of containment logics and forward the `shouldautorotate/willanimate` to your controller. I.e., your main controller could call `shouldautorotate/willanimate` on your `abcController` instance, but then it should know it. As an aside, Apple does not suggest doing like this, but this is the only way if you want to support iOS4.

Alternatively, you might use [UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) for iOS>5.

This resorts to using two methods:

```
@interface UIViewController (UIContainerViewControllerProtectedMethods)

 - (void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController;
 - (void)removeFromParentViewController;

@end
```

[Here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/) you can find a good tutorial. This will not work on iOS4.

Answer (score 0):

In order for view controller to receive shouldautorotate/willanimate calls you need it to be in "view hierarchy". Thus, if you just add its view as a subview, these methods will not get called, but if you push this view controller into navigation controller or present it as a modal view controller or use addChildViewController method(for iOS 5+), view controller will receive those messages. If you just want to add its view as a subview, you can get away with autoresizingMask. (But then I just don't see a point of creating view controller instead of just custom view)